# Daily Capacity Reduction Problem Using IF Condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have some confusion about excel vba. My aim is to determine which shipments are exceed of the daily carton pick capacity or pallet pick capacity. Each month has different carton and pallet amount.

```
 For Each cell In Range("AB2:AB10000")
   For i = 2 To 10000
     If Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "01" Then

        toplam_karton_ocak = toplam_karton_ocak - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_ocak = toplam_palet_ocak - cell(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_ocak < 0 Or toplam_karton_ocak < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If
```

I used "for each " to check every cell in the column and I used 12 "if" conditions to assign date to the right capacity. I tried to decrease the capacity when every shipment came. My aim is that if pallet or carton pick is less than zero, giving a message on the screen.

Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) --> It takes 4th and 5th digits of the day. i.e the date is "22.05.2020".It receives "05" and that means "may"
My problem is I could not do this for every day. I just did it for month but it is useless because i have to check it separately for every single day. What should i do?

You can find the full code below:

```
Sub New_DC()

New_DC Makro

Range("Z1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BOOKING ONLY DATES"
Range("Z2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT([@[BOOKING_DATE_OR]],8)"
Range("AA1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Column1 "
Range("AA2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=DATE(RIGHT([@[BOOKING ONLY DATES]],4),MID([@[BOOKING ONLY DATES]],3,2),LEFT([@[BOOKING ONLY DATES]],2))"
Range("AB1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "New DC"
Range("AB2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-14]=""1-YES"",IF(ISBLANK([@[Sum of Carrier Lead Time]]),[@[Column1 ]]-[@[Sum of TRANSPORT_DURATION]],[@[Column1 ]]-[@[Sum of Carrier Lead Time]]),IF(ISBLANK([@[Sum of Carrier Lead Time]]),[@[END_TIME_UTC]]-[@[Sum of TRANSPORT_DURATION]],[@[END_TIME_UTC]]-[@[Sum of Carrier Lead Time]]))"
Columns("AB:AB").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Columns("Z:AA").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("AE11").Select

 Range("Table1[[#Headers],[New DC]]").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
    Key:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[New DC]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("AC2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF([@[Booking_Appointment_Made (groups)]]=""1-YES"",1,0)"
Range("AC2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
    Key:=Range("AC2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Columns("AC:AC").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True


    Range("AB2").Select

Dim toplam_karton_ocak As Long, toplam_karton_subat As Long, toplam_karton_mart As Long, toplam_karton_nisan As Long
Dim toplam_karton_mayis As Long, toplam_karton_haziran As Long, toplam_karton_temmuz As Long, toplam_karton_agustos As Long
Dim toplam_karton_eylul As Long, toplam_karton_ekim As Long, toplam_karton_kasim As Long, toplam_karton_aralik As Long

Dim toplam_palet_ocak As Integer, toplam_palet_subat As Integer, toplam_palet_mart As Integer, toplam_palet_nisan As Integer
Dim toplam_palet_mayis As Integer, toplam_palet_haziran As Integer, toplam_palet_temmuz As Integer, toplam_palet_agustos As Integer
Dim toplam_palet_eylul As Integer, toplam_palet_ekim As Integer, toplam_palet_kasim As Integer, toplam_palet_aralik As Integer

toplam_karton_ocak = 15000
toplam_palet_ocak = 300

toplam_karton_subat = 15000
toplam_palet_subat = 300

toplam_karton_mart = 15000
toplam_palet_mart = 300

toplam_karton_nisan = 17000
toplam_palet_nisan = 400

toplam_karton_mayis = 17500
toplam_palet_mayis = 600

toplam_karton_haziran = 18000
toplam_palet_haziran = 300

toplam_karton_temmuz = 20000
toplam_palet_temmuz = 300

toplam_karton_agustos = 25000
toplam_palet_agustos = 500

toplam_karton_eylul = 42000
toplam_palet_eylul = 900

toplam_karton_ekim = 35000
toplam_palet_ekim = 750

toplam_karton_kasim = 27000
toplam_palet_kasim = 750

toplam_karton_aralik = 22500
toplam_palet_aralik = 750

For Each cell In Range("AB2:AB10000")
For i = 2 To 10000
     If Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "01" Then

        toplam_karton_ocak = toplam_karton_ocak - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_ocak = toplam_palet_ocak - cell(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_ocak < 0 Or toplam_karton_ocak < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "02" Then

        toplam_karton_subat = toplam_karton_subat - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_subat = toplam_palet_subat - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_subat < 0 Or toplam_karton_subat < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "03" Then

        toplam_karton_mart = toplam_karton_mart - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_mart = toplam_palet_mart - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_mart < 0 Or toplam_karton_mart < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "04" Then

        toplam_karton_nisan = toplam_karton_nisan - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_nisan = toplam_palet_nisan - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_nisan < 0 Or toplam_karton_nisan < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "05" Then

        toplam_karton_mayis = toplam_karton_mayis - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_mayis = toplam_palet_mayis - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_mayis < 0 Or toplam_karton_mayis < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If


     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "06" Then

        toplam_karton_haziran = toplam_karton_haziran - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_haziran = toplam_palet_haziran - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_haziran < 0 Or toplam_karton_haziran < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "07" Then

        toplam_karton_temmuz = toplam_karton_temmuz - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_temmuz = toplam_palet_temmuz - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_temmuz < 0 Or toplam_karton_temmuz < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "08" Then

        toplam_karton_agustos = toplam_karton_agustos - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_agustos = toplam_palet_agustos - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_agustos < 0 Or toplam_karton_agustos < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "09" Then

        toplam_karton_eylul = toplam_karton_eylul - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_eylul = toplam_palet_eylul - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_eylul < 0 Or toplam_karton_eylul < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "10" Then

        toplam_karton_ekim = toplam_karton_ekim - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_ekim = toplam_palet_ekim - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_ekim < 0 Or toplam_karton_ekim < 0 Then

            MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "11" Then

        toplam_karton_kasim = toplam_karton_kasim - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_kasim = toplam_palet_kasim - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_kasim < 0 Or toplam_karton_kasim < 0 Then

           MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If

     ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2) = "12" Then

        toplam_karton_aralik = toplam_karton_aralik - Cells(i, 20)
        toplam_palet_aralik = toplam_palet_aralik - Cells(i, 19)

        If toplam_palet_aralik < 0 Or toplam_karton_aralik < 0 Then

           MsgBox (Cells(i, 1).Value & " nolu shipment kapasiteyi aşmaktadır.")

        End If
     End If
Next i
Next cell

Columns("AB:AB").Select


Range("AF6").Select

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Seems like you would want to make the day a variable... you may want to include a bit more of your code for it to make sense.

Comment: I added all of them. Thanks :)